# Setting server status to 404 .net

Tags: c#, .net, webserver

I'm working on a web server and I'm trying to give 404 error message to the client when one of my applications is stopped.

```
private static int _firstFibonacci = 1;
    private static int _secondFibonacci = 1;      

    public override string HandleRequest(string[] parameters)
    {
        if (_isStopped)
        {

        } 
        Console.Write(_firstFibonacci + "\n" + _secondFibonacci + "\n");

        int nextFibonacci = _firstFibonacci + _secondFibonacci;

        Console.WriteLine(nextFibonacci);

        _firstFibonacci = _secondFibonacci;
        _secondFibonacci = nextFibonacci;

        return nextFibonacci.ToString();
    }
```

This is my application and at the server class I didn't start it, so my _isStopped bool is true and it goes in to that if block. My problem is I can't return error 404 in that if block i tried the methods on stackoverflow and I don't want to use custom 404 error. By the way I'm using HttpListener on the Server class.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't see any web server related code?

Comment: The best, use break point, and see line by line

Answer (score 0):

To return a 404 throw an [`HttpException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with 404 as its first parameter:

```
throw new HttpException(404, "Service Is Unabilable");
```

However, if the URL is valid, then that is the wrong HTTP status to return. A server side issue with an otherwise valid request (eg. you've stopped the service) should result in a 5xx series status. Specifically 503: "Service Unavailable" fits this case. Again you throw an `HttpException`.

Comment: But it's just throwing an exception i need to get response on the client side. I mean i need to see the default error page on Chrome etc.

Comment: @dgknrdm ASP.NET handles `HttpException` into the normal – filters (in MVC), modules, custom error pages, etc.– pipeline; the client will see whatever your web site is set up to show for that HTTP status.